# Heavy mass vs light mass in circular motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force

If I have 2 spheres with different mass in a spinning Y shaped tube(no water is in the tube),

[image: heavy vs light ball in circular motion1]
              
[image: heavy vs light ball in circular motion2]

which one will go higher because of inertia and centripetal force, the light sphere or the heavy sphere?
Or if I have 2 masses, a light one and a heavy one on opposite sides but at the same distance from the centre of a spinning table, which mass will move farther from the centre the heavy one or the light one?

[image: heavy vs light ball in circular motion3]

i think that the light sphere will go up higher(will have bigger acceleration) because there has to be a balance between the mass and the acceleration as long as the force is the same,

for example if you push a heavy object and with the same force pushed another light object the light object will travel farther(will have more acceleration): let us assume the force=2N, and mass A=4kg, mass B=2kg,

acceleration of mass(A) $$a_A=\frac{f}{m}=\frac{2}{4}=0.5 m/s^2$$

acceleration of mass(B) $$a_B=\frac{f}{m}=\frac{2}{2}=1 m/s^2$$

But in a centrifuge, denser substances and particles in the solution move outward in the radial direction. At the same time, objects that are less dense  move to the centre?

Answer (score 1):

Both masses stay at the same hight, for any speed, since the component of the weight going in direction to the center to make up the centripetal force  is proportional to the weight. If you spin a fluid in a vertical drum  the heavier part goes to the outside , like the heavier part goes down if you let the fluid or gas just stand under the gravitational force